# Error while compiling java file with GCC

Tags: java, gcc, compiler-errors

I wrote a small java program in Netbeans. It compiles and runs perfectly. But I also need to compile it in javac in Linux because this homework is tested there. Whenever I attempt, I get the following compile error message. Do you have any idea about this message?

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/glibc-2.14.1/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/elf/start.S:109: undefined reference to `main'
```

I just write the following line for import a library

```
 import java.sql.*;
```

I am just using println except sql operations. The beginning of my code is below:

```
Connection conn = null;
try{
    String username = ".....";
    String password = "....";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/.....";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    System.out.println("Database connection extablished.");
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Cannot connect to database server");
}
```

After this part of code, nothing special, just ordinary lines.

Comment: Its complaining you don't have a main method. Can you show you have one? BTW Why are you using gcc to compile Java? It hasn't been updated for many years.

Comment: Compile Java program with GCC??

Comment: Can you post the command-line you're invoking?  I'm hopeful that this is mistagged `gcc` and should be `gcj`...?

Comment: It would be easier just to install a Linux JDK instead of using gcc.If you HAVE to use gcc (which I doubt), use gcj instead.

Comment: I have a main method. Because it is homework and tested in linux, I must be sure that my program runs in linux. Otherwise, It doesn't make any sense. I think, it may not found the sql jar. How could add a jar file in corresponding java library?

Comment: @Shnkc As everyone has said, the JDK *does* run in Linux perfectly, you don't need to use GCJ for that reason!

Comment: Java class files are platform-independent. You do not need to recompile your Java source code on Linux. You can run the class files that you compiled on Windows on a Linux machine (provided that you have a JRE on Linux).

Comment: @nos I think you mean `public static void main(String[] args)` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that error may be because you're not defining a main method, and the compiler therefore can't find it.

However, I have to ask why you're using GCC? Normal JDK is available on Linux and should be your preferred choice unless you have a very good reason otherwise! If Netbeans isn't compiling your application on Linux then it's probably because you haven't set something up properly or installed the JDK - you can (and should) use the JDK rather than GCJ, which is now largely unmaintained.

You can either grab it through your package manager or download it separately [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You *don't* need to (re-)compile it for linux. It's Java. The generated class file (from windows) will run on Linux *and* Windows, you just need a JRE or JDK on the target host.

Answer (score 0):

Compile with [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html), not GCC (or [GCJ](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) if you really want something "GCCish").

Comment: @Shnkc mmmh ok so why did you mention GCC?

Comment: When I see gcc path in the error message, I just said it in that way

Comment: It's using the javac of gcj. Remove gjc alltogether, it's more trouble than it is worth, and install a proper JDK.